# laravel uploading image in database with wrong path

Tags: database, laravel, upload

Uploading a images to the database give the wrong path.

[image]

It should referense to my storage/uploads directory

Also i have done this command to make the storage folder public.

```
php artisan storage:link
```

enctype

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

My code:

```
public function store(Posts $posts){
    $validation = request()->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'ingredients' => 'required',
        'prepartion' => 'required',
        'categorie_id' => 'required',
        'image' => 'required|file|image|max:5000'
    ]);

    Posts::create($validation);

    $posts->update([
        'image' => request()->image->store('uploads', 'public')
    ]);

    return redirect('/admin');
}
```

If more info is needed please let me know

Comment: Laravel has [documentation on File Uploads](https://laravel.com/docs/master/filesystem#file-uploads), might want to take a look there and see if that helps

Answer (score 1):

You should have to you Storage Facade and use disk which should defined in config/filesystem.php to store image.

```
Storage::disk('public')->put($path, $content);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may call the putFile method on the Storage facade to perform the same file manipulation

```
$posts->update([
     'image' => \Storage::putFile('uploads', request()->file('image'));
]);
```